# moving element to different parent within several divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to move an element from one parent to another parent within several divs. I'm guessing there's something wrong with the selectors.

```
for (var i = $('.auction').length; i >= 1; i--) {
    $('.auc' + [i] + ' .aucimginfo .aucinfopivot').prependTo( $('auc' + [i] + ' .bidtime'));
};
```

Comment: please, post your HTML.

Comment: $('**DON'T YOU NEED . HERE?**auc' + [i] + ' .bidtime')